# How to create a graphical schema for Postgres database?

Tags: postgresql, schema, sqltools

I have got a sql file where is configured a database in PostgreSQL technology. I created a database from sql file but from code it is hard to understand action/connecting between the tables. Is it some tool which show all the connections between tables for PostgreSQL?

Comment: Wich was the best for you? and also free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- pgDesigner
- Data Architect
- Datastudio
- DbDesigner fork
- DbSchema
- dbwrench
- DeZign for Database

Please take a look to this [list](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/GUI_Database_Design_Tools) of tools.